# Best practice for sharing data between UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf

**TLDR:**

Basically, I want to be able to know when a CheckBox is checked in an embedded UserControl.

**The Question:**

I have a UserControl for my application's settings. The settings UserControl has sections on it (Hardware settings, Network settings, etc...) that are their own separate UserControls.

The settings UserControl has a ListBox with each section and a Grid to display each section's UserControl when clicked:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SettingsListBox" SelectionChanged="SettingsListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBoxItem>Hardware</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Network</ListBoxItem
</ListBox>

<Grid x:Name="SettingsSectionGrid" />
```

I assign each section like this:

```
private void SettingsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    // Clear the grid
    SettingsSectionGrid.Children.Clear();

    switch (SettingsListBox.SelectedIndex) {
        // Hardware
        case 0:
            SettingsSectionGrid.Children.Add(new HardwareSection());
            break;
        // Network
        case 0:
            SettingsSectionGrid.Children.Add(new NetworkSection());
            break;
        // Hardware by default
        default:
            SettingsSectionGrid.Children.Add(new HardwareSection());
            break;
    }
}
```

The issue is that if you click on another section it doesn't remember the settings from the previous section and I need the main UserControl that houses the section UserControls to know the data that's been entered.

What's the best practice for creating something like this and how can I have the settings UserControl communicate with the section UserControls?

For example, if the user types in an IP address in the Network section I need the Settings UserControl to be able to know that information to save it and present it again should the user go back to that section.

Thanks!

Comment: don't do this.  if each option has it's own group of controls with their own unique values, make a user control for each of these different types, which can report out it's unique properties.  Then add each, and toggle the visibility of them via the checkbox, instead of adding and removing controls.

Comment: That is a good approach, but I still need the data from the embedded UserControls to be seen by the UserControl that's housing the various sections.

Comment: right, each control would have properties that would represent the values of each of the data points from the inner form, so you could, for example, ask for `NetworkSectionControl.IPAddress`, and get the value stored in that textbox.  And by toggling the visibility of the controls rather than destroying the controls, the controls are able to retain their respective state.

Comment: @TGK: The best practice would be to implement the MVVM design pattern and have the UserControls share a common view model that they bind to.

Comment: They do. I just arranged things improperly. It's working as intended now.